# I can ping my EC2 instance, but I cannot connect through ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

A while back I had created an RHEL EC2 instance.  Set it up correctly and was able to connect to it through putty and WINSCP.  Over time it hasn't been used but until recently it needed to be accessed again.  I went to check to login but wasn't able to.  So i reboot the instance and try to reconnect but I cannot anymore.  I get the error "Network error: Connection refused."

I tried recreating the ppk from pem, and also enable all ports to all IP's.  What could have caused this un-reachability and are there any troubleshooting tips for me to connect to it again?

Comment: Check the DNS name, when you restart an ec2 instance Amazon usually assigns a different DNS name to the instance so you have to update your putty connection properties

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check here:

1. Did you have anything running on the box that might have caused it to become unresponsive over time?  This is somewhat unlikely since you said you rebooted the machine.
2. Check your security group settings to ensure that the firewall is not blocking your SSH port.  The instance has no way of knowing whether connections will actually be accepted by the Amazon network on the SSH listening port.
3. Amazon hardware can fail and cause your instance to become unresponsive.  Go to the Instances page on your EC2 console and see if 2/2 of the status checks are passing.  If less than 2 are passing, this is probably a failed instance situation.

As a last resort, try right-clicking the instance and checking the system log for anything that might have caused the instance to not listen for SSH connections.

Hopefully you have your data on an EBS volume such that you can simply stop and start the instance and have it come up on different hardware.  While it would be nice if Amazon provided console level access to the box, unfortunately they do not presently (as far as I know).

Comment: If hardware is flagged unhealthy, a reboot is enough to transition the box to new hardware, also Amazon usually notifies the owners if the hardware needs to be replaced for what ever reason.

Comment: I can definitely appreciate that if hardware is marked unhealthy these things occur, however, at my work we have been the unfortunate discoverers of such hardware as our instances stop responding in a similar manner.  That said, we have some old instance-store backed instances that are not easily transferred between hardware so it's more of a pain than it should be.

Comment: You do make a good point that this should be detected and notifications sent automatically, though.